# Delete an Excel file after processing in Java

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, servlets, apache-poi

I want to take an input Java file from an HTMl form process it using servlets, and delete it after use.

However I am not able to find any viable solutions for the same. What are the options I can go about to delete the file from the project folder after I am done with it.

Below is my code:

```
public class TryWithResources extends fileUpload{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
            try {
                
                FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse- 
                workspace\\firstDemo\\fileData");
                XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                System.out.println("Enter the sheet you want to search in: ");
                Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
                int n= sc.nextInt(); 
                XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(n-1);
                Iterator<Row> itr=sheet.iterator();
                
                
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    Row row=itr.next();
                    
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();
                    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                        Cell name_cell=row.getCell(0);
                        String name=name_cell.getStringCellValue();
                        if (cell.getRowIndex()!=0 && cell.getStringCellValue().equals("")&& cell.getColumnIndex()!=0){
                            int idate=cell.getColumnIndex();
                            Row first_row=sheet.getRow(0); 
                            Cell date_cell=first_row.getCell(idate);
                            
                            Date sdate=date_cell.getDateCellValue();
                            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");  
                            String  strDate = formatter.format(sdate); 
                            
                                
                        
                            
                            
                          
                                
                            if (AttendanceUtils.DayCheck(sdate)){
                                Locale locale=Locale.getDefault();
                                System.out.println("No entry found for "+name+" on "+ strDate.substring(8,10)+"-"+AttendanceUtils.getmonth( sdate)+"-"+strDate.substring(24,28) +" "+ AttendanceUtils.getDayStringOld(sdate,locale));
                            
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                            
                                
                        }
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        }
                    
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    
                }
                
            catch(Exception e)  
            {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            
    }
}
```

The code for the servlet which helps upload this file is

```
package attendanceApp;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;



public class fileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    

    
        
    

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try {
        ServletFileUpload sf=new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
    
            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            //String file="";
            
            for(FileItem item : multifiles)
            {
                //file =item.getName();
                item.write(new File("C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse-workspace\\firstDemo\\fileData"));
                
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
      }
  }
  public String fileName(String files){
        return files;
//ignore this function, created to explore another solution 
    }
  
  
}
```

I am exploring two options here

1. one to go about using TryWithResources, but I am not sure how it will implement delete operation.
2. to write every file uploaded as fileData, perform functions on it and delte it then and there.

In both the cases I will need to delete the file after use, also to optimise memory it is not really feasible to store every file uploaded.

So, how can I perform the delete functions in the above codes?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, in Windows, it will not release the file until the request is served. So you can't delete the same request. You should have a schedular that can run every 5 minutes and delete files older than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your output file stream is properly closed after writing, and your input file stream is properly closed after reading. Then the file should be good to delete.

If [File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()) returns false, run [File.deleteOnExit()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()).

Comment: I am getting an error on both the functions. Apparently they are not vallid on FileInputStream type

Comment: True. File != FileInputStream

Answer (score 0):

If i use the code

`File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null);`

then i won't have to create a location for file in the disk and hence the file can be deleted on exit from application.
This can be achieved using  the function:

file.deleteOnExit().